# Get rows from last insert statement by specific user

Tags: postgresql, role

I have many users in my web app (not the `postgres` user). Each of them capable of inserting item transactions on their own location.

How to get only rows just inserted by `user_a`?

Comment: Are those users PostgreSQL roles, or stored in a self-defined user table?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres does not save information about who wrote what exactly. If you need this, you have to do it yourself.

To save the [current user or the session user (you decide)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22502312/939860) for every ***inserted*** row, I like to have a tiny meta table of eligible users with a tiny PK column and only safe that value with every row. To keep it simple and fast I don't even add a FK constraint.

Demo code (as admin or superuser):

```
CREATE SCHEMA admin;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA admin FROM public;  -- only for admin

CREATE TABLE admin.login (
  login_id smallserial PRIMARY KEY
, login    text NOT NULL
, note     text
);
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE admin.login FROM public;

INSERT INTO admin.login(login, note) VALUES
  ('postgres', 'default superuser')
, ('user_a'  , 'someuser');          -- INSERT relevant roles

CREATE FUNCTION public.f_login_id()  -- usable by public
  RETURNS int2 AS
$func$
   SELECT login_id FROM admin.login WHERE login = current_user
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER;

CREATE FUNCTION public.f_login_id(text)  -- overloaded function
  RETURNS int2 AS
$func$
   SELECT login_id FROM admin.login WHERE login = $1
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Then add a `created_by` column to each table that's supposed to log the insert role:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN created_by int2 DEFAULT public.f_login_id();
```

This is the simple, basic solution. Any user could alter values in `created_by` unless you do more.

Now this query can be your **solution** (for rows inserted *after* you ran the above). To get all rows inserted by a given role:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  created_by = public.f_login_id('user_a');
```

If you do this a lot, add an index on `(created_by)`.

To also identify the ***latest*** transaction, you could work with the [**`xmin`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html) saved in the header of every row. But that can be a bit tricky:

- [How to view tuples changed in a PostgreSQL transaction?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123145/how-to-view-tuples-changed-in-a-postgresql-transaction/123183#123183)

Or, while you are still inside the inserting transaction:

- [Can I select data inserted in the same uncommited transaction?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98576/can-i-select-data-inserted-in-the-same-uncommited-transaction/98580#98580)

I would also add a column `created_at timestamptz DEFAULT now()` and work with that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table t
WHERE  created_by = public.f_login_id('user_a');
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM my_table
   WHERE  created_by = t.created_by
   AND    created_at > t.created_at
   );
```